# Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. error after multiple 250's

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

We have a php script to send emails, build with codeigniter.

Many of the emails are send correctly each time but there also a couple of errors (after 220 and 221 codes).
the strange part is in the logs there are many 250 statussus and after `250 recipient ok`I receive the error: `<br />Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter`

I can't find something weird in the logs of the mail server either.

The complete error:

```
ERROR 220 {SERVER} Ready <br /><pre>hello: {server} Hello {Bussiness}
250 SIZE
</pre><pre>from: 250 sender ok <noreply@mymail.com>
</pre><pre>to: </pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: <br /><pre>quit: 250 recipient ok <myname@hotmail.com> </pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: 250 recipient ok <mynamek@hotmail.com> <br />Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter
```

So I can't figure out it is a mail server issue or a php script issue. Read some of the same question on SO but it was always a simple configuration error inside PHP, tried some but it doesn't work either.

The PHP script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

class Mailtest extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $config = array(); 
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "server ip";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "port";


        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $subject = 'SMTP test';
        $htmlbody = "lorem ipsum";

        $textbody = strip_tags($htmlbody);

        $this->email->from('noreply@myemail.nl', 'my name');
        $this->email->reply_to('noreply@myemail.nl', 'noreply');
        $this->email->to('name@myemail.nl', 'my name');
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($htmlbody);
        $this->email->set_alt_message($textbody);

        if(!$this->email->send())
        {
            $fout = $this->email->print_debugger();
            var_dump($fout);
        } 
        $this->email->clear();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

ps:

```
code 250 = Requested mail action okay, completed
code 220 = <domain> Service ready
code 221 = <domain> Service closing transmission channel
```

Comment: 220 and 221 and 250 are not error , smtp error codes are 4xx and 5xx format, maybe you hit mail server per hour sending limit or your Ci's mail $config is wrong.

Comment: @B.Mossavari sorry, I ment after those codes